# Google cloud endpoints custom objects

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I was setting up endpoints using google's developer tutorials and I wanted to create my own class besides the auto-generated MyBean one, but when I try to access it, I get a 503 error. I'm having a hard time finding information on using endpoints in android studio so any help would be appreciated. Here is my code in MyEndpoints, and I just want to mention that calling the auto-generated sayHi function still works fine. Its only when I use my function.

```
package com.example.joebruckner.fitnesstracker.backend;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.inject.Named;

/**
 * An endpoint class we are exposing
 */
@Api(name = "myApi", version = "v1", namespace = @ApiNamespace(
        ownerDomain = "backend.fitnesstracker.joebruckner.example.com",
        ownerName = "backend.fitnesstracker.joebruckner.example.com",
        packagePath = ""))

public class MyEndpoint {

    /**
     * A simple endpoint method that takes a name and says Hi back
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "sayHi")
    public MyBean sayHi(@Named("name") String name) {
        MyBean response = new MyBean();
        response.setData("Hi, " + name);

        return response;
    }

    /**
     * A test to see how my own objects work
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "getWorkout")
    public WorkoutFob getWorkout(@Named("test") String test) {
        WorkoutFob workout = new WorkoutFob(1, 2, new Date());
        return workout;
    }

}
```

---

```
01-02 17:28:21.939    4802-4802/joebruckner.fitnesstracker I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@620150 time:49832335
01-02 17:28:23.232    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
01-02 17:28:23.232    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ {
01-02 17:28:23.232    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ "code": 503,
01-02 17:28:23.232    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ "errors": [
01-02 17:28:23.232    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ {
01-02 17:28:23.232    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ "domain": "global",
01-02 17:28:23.232    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ "message": "",
01-02 17:28:23.232    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ "reason": "backendError"
01-02 17:28:23.232    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ }
01-02 17:28:23.232    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ ],
01-02 17:28:23.232    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ "message": ""
01-02 17:28:23.232    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ }
01-02 17:28:23.233    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
01-02 17:28:23.233    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
01-02 17:28:23.233    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
01-02 17:28:23.233    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
01-02 17:28:23.233    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
01-02 17:28:23.233    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
01-02 17:28:23.233    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
01-02 17:28:23.233    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ at joebruckner.fitnesstracker.EndpointsAsyncTask.doInBackground(EndpointsAsyncTask.java:34)
01-02 17:28:23.233    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ at joebruckner.fitnesstracker.EndpointsAsyncTask.doInBackground(EndpointsAsyncTask.java:17)
01-02 17:28:23.233    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-02 17:28:23.233    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-02 17:28:23.233    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-02 17:28:23.234    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-02 17:28:23.234    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-02 17:28:23.234    4802-4827/joebruckner.fitnesstracker W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
01-02 17:28:23.418    4802-4828/joebruckner.fitnesstracker V/RenderScript﹕ Application requested CPU execution
01-02 17:28:23.423    4802-4828/joebruckner.fitnesstracker V/RenderScript﹕ 0xa130b200 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
```

---

```
package joebruckner.fitnesstracker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.util.Pair;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.joebruckner.fitnesstracker.backend.myApi.MyApi;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json.AndroidJsonFactory;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by joebruckner on 12/31/14.
 */
public class EndpointsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Context, String>, Void, String> {
    private static MyApi myApi = null;
    private final String PROJECT_CODE = "---------";
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
        if (myApi == null) {
            MyApi.Builder b = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                    .setRootUrl("https://" + PROJECT_CODE + ".appspot.com/_ah/api/");
            myApi = b.build();
        }

        context = params[0].first;
        String name = params[0].second;

        try {
            return myApi.getWorkout("Test 1").execute().toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the backend first, by selecting the cloud backend on top if you are using Android Studio. If so, we need to see your WorkoutFob class too, as well as the way you use it.

Please update with your AsyncThread code so we can help identify the error.

EDIT: 
I see the problem I believe. In your try catch block you are returning e.getMessage() instead of null like you should to the onPostExecute. Instead, return null as opposed to the e.getMessage(). The Toast is most likely causing a problem since it is trying to toast a null item. Add an if statement inside onPostExecute to test if the result is null or not from the doInBackground. Provide two different Toasts for if the result is null or not, and Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage) in the doInBackground instead. Let me know if this does any good.

Also, you could make the Context variable public and static, and create your AsyncTask as an object to add the context value, instead of passing a Pair into the AsyncTask. Just a bit easier to read and use

Comment: Yea, no problem, ill add the async code when i get back to my computer. Regarding running the backend, do i still have to run it in AS if i deployed it?

Comment: You need to run the backend within AS, and you can check if it is successfully running via Android Terminal output that you see when you start the backend. Also, check http://localhost:8080 once you start it to ensure it is running. At that point, you can run your client side program to test it and see if it works. Your async thread code should include try and catch block for instantiating and running the backend objects as well.

Comment: I've add my async code. I tried it with the backend running in AS and I get the same results

Comment: Editing with my answer

Comment: I changed it so the catch clause returns null and the onPostExecute prints different in that special case. When I run it, it prints the special case, so I'm getting an IOexception. The IOexception is the 503 error so I still don't understand why thats happening.

Comment: Hmm, try removing the .setRootUrl() in the builder creation in doInTheBackground method. 503 error is a server side problem so this is related to the backend. Just make sure your backend is running on localhost:8080 before running client side.

Comment: Make sure in your AndroidManifest.xml there is the following: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: When I first created the endpoint backend it auto-generates some sample code to test it which includes the "sayHi" function. I already tested to make sure the sayHi function works and it does. I then deployed the backend to google cloud so it no longer has to be run locally, I tested this and it works. The only time I get an error is when I use my custom backend object, "WorkoutFob", so I don't believe the error is because I am not deploying the backend correctly although I might be misunderstanding something.

Comment: I checked and I do have the internet permission